# basic post put delete methods are not working in laravel while get method is good

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
Route::get('getrequest',function(){
    return'get listened';
});
Route::Post('postrequest',function(){
    //echo "post listened";
});
Route::put('putrequest',function(){
    return'put listened';
});
Route::delete('deleterequest',function(){
    return'delete listened';
});
```

Comment: Please say something about it.

Comment: How are you accesing the post, put and delete routes? Also you should read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section from the help center, because you're question offers very little information.

Comment: You have to put the `_method` field in your forms containing the method name if you use methods other than GRT/POST.

Comment: @Bogdan i am new at this and just typing the url:localhost:8000/postrequest to access post

Comment: @TheAlpha sorry sir i didnt  get you

Comment: [Check this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Comment: Any URL you type into the browser's address bar will send a GET request. For other requests you need to use forms like described in the Laravel documentation @TheAlpha linked to, or use other methods such as JavaScript XHR requests, cURL, etc. although using forms is most likely the way to go here.

Comment: Try using [LaravelCollective HTML and Forms](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html). It will make this easier for you.

Comment: `Route::Post`  this wrong rewrite as `Route::post`

Comment: You need to work on your basic understanding about Forms and sending the relevant data across pages.